# C# List items empty after button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am trying to understand the lifecycle that is taking place here. I have a asp list view where I get item ids and write them to a list like so.

```
 protected void ShareWith_OnItemBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
            {
                ListViewDataItem currentItemId = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataKey currentDataKey = this.lvShareWithPanel.DataKeys[currentItemId.DataItemIndex];
                int FriendId = Convert.ToInt32(currentDataKey["SharedUserId"]);
                CurrentList.Add(FriendId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where my list is defined outside the method

```
private List<int> CurrentList = new List<int>();
```

after, the user adds some new items to the list then click on an asp button to continue. I am running a comparison of the current list versus the new one but observing in debug after the button click I find that my list "CurrentList" is now empty. Why might the list, which is outside any method, be effected?

Thanks for the help understanding

Comment: Please check declaring your CurrentList as static. Let me know if this works!

Comment: @mihirj What a bad advice! ASP.NET is a multithread environment and static fields are shared by all threads.

Comment: defining the list as static did work. as I don't know much about multithreading, what is the possible repercussions of doing this?

Comment: do not use a static list - this will be shared with every user/request for that page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list has no state value. So you need to store the list in either ViewState, Session state or otherwise.

Every ASP.NET page loses its values between page loads and only gets them back from state or if you enter them every time. Most controls store values in ViewState, which is page specific. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should help.

Answer (score 2):

All page's objects will be disposed at the end of the page's life-cycle. So you need to create and fill your list on every postback (or store it in `Session` what i wouldn't recommend).

You could use page's `PreRender` event to ensure that all events are already triggered:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    // why do you need a list as field variable at all? I assume a local variable is fine
    List<int> CurrentList = new List<int>();
    foreach(var currentItemId in lvShareWithPanel.Items)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataKey currentDataKey = lvShareWithPanel.DataKeys[currentItemId.DataItemIndex];
        int FriendId = Convert.ToInt32(currentDataKey["SharedUserId"]);
        CurrentList.Add(FriendId);
    }
    // do something with the list
}
```

Note that you should not make it `static` as someone commented. That means you would use the same "instance" for every user and every request.

Here you can see all events:

[image]

Comment: very informative. I will try your approach. I was actually considering doing something like this but first wanted to try with the what I had available in the listview control.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is *stateless*, therefore the data is lost during Postback. You need to keep track of your `CurrentList` manually e.g. in the Session/ViewState.

```
public List<int> CurrentList
{
    get
    {
        return (List<int>)Session["CurrentList"] ?? new List<int>();
    }
    set
    {
        Session["CurrentList"] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list into ViewState and in PageLoad event, assign the List stored in ViewState to your class level List. This happens because of the Page Life Cycle where objects are disposed.